# Setting value_counts that lower than a threshold as others

Tags: pandas

I want to set item with count<=1 as others, code for input table:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['a','a','a','b','b','c','d']})
```

input table:

```
item
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    b
5    c
6    d
```

expected output:

```
  item result
0    a      a
1    a      a
2    a      a
3    b      b
4    b      b
5    c  other
6    d  other
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with check if all values are duplciates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
df['result'] = df.item.where(df.item.duplicated(keep=False), 'other')
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with greater by 1 by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df['result'] = df.item.where(df.groupby('item')['item'].transform('size').gt(1), 'other')
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['result'] = df.item.where(df['item'].map(df['item'].value_counts()).gt(1), 'other')
```

---

```
print (df)
  item result
0    a      a
1    a      a
2    a      a
3    b      b
4    b      b
5    c  other
6    d  other
```

Comment: From the docs, `Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other.`. So one needs to set the condition as the opposite of what I would naturally do :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`Series.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
In [926]: import numpy as np

In [927]: df['result'] = np.where(df.groupby('item')['item'].transform('count').le(1), 'other', df.item)

In [928]: df
Out[928]: 
  item result
0    a      a
1    a      a
2    a      a
3    b      b
4    b      b
5    c  other
6    d  other
```

**OR** use `Groupby.size` with `merge`:

```
In [917]: x = df.groupby('item').size().reset_index()

In [919]: ans = df.merge(x)
In [921]: ans['result'] = np.where(ans[0].le(1), 'other', ans.item)

In [923]: ans = ans.drop(0, 1)

In [924]: ans
Out[924]: 
  item result
0    a      a
1    a      a
2    a      a
3    b      b
4    b      b
5    c  other
6    d  other
```